# RelativeLayout content can not be seen

Tags: android, layout

Like the following layout shows, when the items in list are too much, more than one screen.

I can not see the following LinearLayout content when I drag down.

How to solve this problem?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/UserIDStatic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/UserID" />
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using a `<ScrollView>` instead

Comment: put hieght of list view or put scrollview in ur layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >   <!-- use a definate dimension here -->
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/UserIDStatic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/UserID" />
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or else put both `ListView` and `LinearLayout` in `ScrollView`

or as bellow comment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientatio="verticle" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
           android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >  
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.5"


            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserIDStatic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/UserID" />
            .
            .
            .
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A better solution might be to put the list view in a separate linear layout, change the relative layout also to a linear one, and use [weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight). Also please note that `ListViews` should not be put inside `ScrollViews` as specified in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: yes, assigning weights will be good idea if that app should support multiple similar screens

Answer (score 0):

There are two options comes in picture.

1. Instead of Relative layout Use Vertical Linear layout with appropriate wieght to listview  and inner linear layout (eg. 0.7 and 0.3)
2. Use same Relative layout as above with inner LinearLayout to alignparentbottom = true
   and listview above="@innerLinearLayout" linearlayout.

This might solve your problem.
Using specific height for listview might cause different look in UI for different sized screens.